# Locked out of a Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: locked-out

My phone was stolen recently, and I'm trying to use my wife's old S2 as a temporary replacement.
She had a password screenlock, and she can't remember what it was. When I put in my new SIM, the screenlock is still there. Is there a way to get around it?

Comment: was usb debugging turned on in the developer options? edit: is the phone connected to the internet

Comment: The phone is connected to the internet. I don't know if usb debugging was turned on, sorry.

Comment: then just try attempting to unlock it. After 30 tries, it will have an option to enter email id and password (Google one)

Comment: I am currently at 40 tries without any option to enter email id and password. Every 5 attempts it forces me to wait for 30 sec, that's all.

Comment: Have you checked with our [locked-out tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) already? Contains a lot of pointers.

Comment: I have. I'm gonna do that trick to factory reset now. Thanks for trying to help, guys.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

- From your computer, open [Play Store:Android Device Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.adm&hl=en).
- Log in from the same Google ID which you used to set up your phone.
- Click on *Install* and select the locked phone. In few minutes, your Android Device Manager will be installed on your phone.
- Now open [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) with your computer.
- There will be a button named Lock. Click that and set up a custom password and finish by clicking *Lock*.
- The screen lock will be replaced by the custom password you just set up.
- Voila! Use the password and unlock your phone!